# Getting Started with Cloudflare's HTMLRewriter

Tags: javascript, html, json, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am entirely new at using HTMLRewriter, but have some general js/html experience. My task is relatively simple, but I am really just not sure how HTMLRewriter works. What I need to do is:

1. Retrieve a static HTML page
2. Get the links from your previously deployed JSON response
3. Use HTMLRewriter to add these links to the static HTML page
4. Return the transformed HTML page from the Worker

I have the url "https://static-links-page.signalnerve.workers.dev/," but it is not local. So what I would like to know is:

1. What is the correct way to copy/store this static html page in order to make changes with HTMLRewriter?
2. How should I go about adding my own JSON url array to the retrieved HTML page using HTMLRewriter? I read about the setInnerContent function, but am not sure if that is what I should be using.
3. Finally, and I’m pretty sure this is straightforward, but what is the right way to return the modified html page?

Again, my experience is in writing html/js together, so I have very little experience doing everything from within a single js file, which is from what I understand one of the biggest benefits of cloudflare. I might be approaching this incorrectly, asking the wrong questions, or completely off track, so any help is greatly appreciated.

My code so far, though knowingly flawed, is below:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
/**
 * Respond with hello worker text
 * @param {Request} request
 */

 var myArray = [
   {
     "name": "Github", "url": "https://github.com/"
   },

   {
     "name": "LinkedIn", "url": "https://linkedin.com/"
   },

   {
     "name": "Firebase", "url": "https://test-login-1573079166139.firebaseapp.com/"
   }
 ]



async function handleRequest(request) {

  //I am not sure if this is the correct way to copy/store a webpage
  var basic_response = fetch('https://static-links-page.signalnerve.workers.dev');

  //I know I have to do something here with this .on() function
  const rewriter = new HTMLRewriter(basic_response)
    .on()
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  console.log(rewriter);
  var pathname = url.pathname;

  if (pathname == '/links')
  {

    var obj =  JSON.stringify (myArray);

    return new Response(obj, {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
  }

  else
  {
    var result =  JSON.stringify (rewriter);

    //This does not work, and I am not sure what the correct way
    //to return my modified webpage would be

    return new Response(rewriter, {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://qwtel.com/posts/software/how-to-use-htmlrewriter-for-web-scraping/ or here https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples